# Test subfunctions in Octave

Tags: unit-testing, octave

I define some [subfunctions](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.1/Subfunctions.html) in my Octave's .m file, and would like to use [the built-in self-test](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.2.1/Test-Functions.html) in Octave `%test` to test these subfunctions like unit test.

My .m file looks like this:

```
function A = fn1()
   A = 1
end

function B = fn2()
   B = 2
end

%!test
%!assert (fn2(), 2)
```

But I was told:

> !!!!! test failed
>
> 'fn2' undefined near line 2 column 9

I would like to know if it is possible to define subfunctions and test it with Octave's built-in test feature. Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

I came from Java/Python world and am new to Octave. When I start working on some problem using Octave, I try to look for some built-in testing feature in Octave to test some "private" functions in Octave. The "private" function equivalent I found in Octave seems to be "subfunctions", and the built-in test feature in Octave is the `%test` self-test, that is why I am looking for a way to do self-test for subfunctions in Octave.

Comment: @Andy I am new to Octave, and I thought it doesn't matter in this question so I didn't include the filename. Does the file name matter in this case?

Comment: there is a difference if the base filename is the same as the function (then called function file) or not (then called script file). Typically you write tests in a function file and the "main" function calls the subfunctions during the test

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't write tests to subfunctions.  The tests work by running
the code in the test block.  The test fails if the code in the
test block errors.  Typically the test unit would call the
function being tested somewhere in the code test.

However, subfunctions only exist in the scope of their parent
functions.  They will not be available in any other scope and so
cannot be called.  The test unit will fail because the function is not
defined.

This is actually a quite common question.  The typical answer is that
a subfunction exists only to be called somewhere by the parent.  So
instead, you should write a test unit that will cover the call to that
subfunction.  If it becomes too difficult, then your parent function
may be doing too much stuff and you should consider having multiple
functions.